# Returning Nan while my all values are number type

Tags: javascript, function

i'm making the summary function that will show the summary of myToDos, but in console it shows "You have NaN meetings today!" while i'm using all the variables of number type.

```js
let myTodos={
    day: 'Monday',
    meetings: 0,
    meetDone: 0,

    addMeeting: function(num){
        this.meetings = this.meetings + num;  
    },
    meetDone: function(meet=0) {
        this.meetDone = this.meetDone + meet;
    },
    resetDay: function(){
        this.meetings = 0;
        this.meetDone = 0;
    },
    summary: function(){
        let leftmeetings = this.meetings - this.meetDone;
        return `You have ${leftmeetings} meetings today!`
    }
}

myTodos.addMeeting(5);
myTodos.meetDone(3);
console.log(myTodos.summary());
```

I expect the output as

> javascript

```
"You have 2 meetings today!"
```

Comment: You defined `meetDone` both as a number property and a method. (Functions can't be subtracted sensibly, thus `NaN`) Separate the names, and your code works. Voting to close as typo

Comment: You have duplicated properties in your object.. `meetDone`. I don't think it will work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you have duplicate properties.

Renaming `meetDone` to `done` will remove the conflict.

```
let myTodos = {
  day: "Monday",
  meetings: 0,
  done: 0,

  addMeeting: function(num) {
    this.meetings = this.meetings + num;
  },
  meetDone: function(meet = 0) {
    this.done = this.done + meet;
  },
  resetDay: function() {
    this.meetings = 0;
    this.meetDone = 0;
  },
  summary: function() {
    let leftmeetings = this.meetings - this.done;
    return `You have ${leftmeetings} meetings today!`;
  }
};

myTodos.addMeeting(5);
myTodos.meetDone(3);
console.log(myTodos.summary());
```

Output:

> You have 2 meetings today!